# How to fill mega menu by two related table in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two table ,ProductGroup and ProductBrand,these are my models

```
  public partial class ProductBrand
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ProductBrand()
    {
        this.ProductGroup = new HashSet<ProductGroup>();
    }

    public int ProductBrandID { get; set; }
    public string ProductBrandTitle { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ProductGroup> ProductGroup { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
  public partial class ProductGroup
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ProductGroup()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Products>();
    }

    public int ProductGroupID { get; set; }
    public int ProductBrandID { get; set; }
    public string ProductGroupTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductBrand ProductBrand { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my partial view that shows dynamic mega menu

```html
@model IEnumerable<BehinFaraz.Models.ProductGroup>
<li class="dropdown dropdown-mm" dir="rtl">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">products  <b class="caret"></b></a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mm dropdown-menu-persist">
    <li class="row"  dir="rtl">
        <ul class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-header "><font color='#01747b'><strong> @item.ProductBrand.ProductBrandTitle </strong></font></li>

            
                foreach (var item1 in Model.Where(model=>model.ProductBrandID==model.ProductBrand.ProductBrandID) )
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item1.ProductGroupTitle, "ShowProductByGroup", "Product",new {id=item1.ProductGroupID},null)</li>
                }
               
            }
        </ul>
       
    </li>
                       
</ul>
```

and this is controller

```
public ActionResult ShowGroup()
    {
         return PartialView();
    }
```

i want to show productgroup that has special productbrandid,and show each productgroup under its productbrand,but it shows all productgroup under every productbrand

Comment: the code shows nothing about how you're fetching this data, so how can we know what's going wrong? how is the data getting into the view? Also why can't you post text for your view code just like the rest of it? Pictures of code are no good really. Code is text, it doesn't need an image.

Comment: Also `foreach var item in Model` doesn't make much sense - what does this loop through? The model seems to be a single ProductGroup object? And the Where condition in your inner loop appears to be a tautology - effectively matching the same field to itself (albeit via a different route in the EF object)

Comment: im trying to send my partail view

Comment: That clarifies exactly nothing, sorry. I know you're using a partial view, but not _how_ you're using it. Please try to explain better, and also replace your picture with text. Also give an example of expected output, because the code in your view makes so little sense that it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I _suspect_ that your view's model ought to be a _list_ of ProductGroup objects, and then you want to loop through those, and then loop through the list of ProductBrand objects within each one, but you really need to clarify your intention. Like I said your current code is pretty much nonsense.

Comment: first i want to show productbrand and then i want to show product group related to productbrand under each product brand,if my partialview is wrong would you plz guide me?

Comment: Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be right I think, assuming you're pulling back the data from the database correctly, which unfortunately you haven't shown.

You already have an `IEnumerable<ProductGroup>` as a property of ProductBrand (look at your ProductBrand class's properties!). This defines the relationship between brand and group. So the model can just be an `IEnumerable<ProductBrand>`. The you can loop through the brands, and for each brand, then loop through all the products within the brand.

It's implicit which ProductGroup objects belong to which ProductBrand, because they're already listed as properties of a specific instances of ProductBrand:

```
@using BehinFaraz.Models
@model IEnumerable<ProductBrand>
<li class="dropdown dropdown-mm" dir="rtl">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products  <b class="caret"></b></a>
<!-- Dropdown Menu -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mm dropdown-menu-persist">
    <li class="row"  dir="rtl">
        <ul class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (ProductBrand brand in Model)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-header "><font color='#01747b'><strong> @brand.ProductBrandTitle</strong></font></li>


                foreach (ProductGroup group in brand.ProductGroup )
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(group.ProductGroupTitle,"ShowProductByGroup","Product",new {id=group.ProductGroupID})</li>
                }

            }
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks alot,mega menu problem has been solved by your solution,but another problem has occured,problem is that new {id=group.ProductGroupID} dosent send productgroupid to ShowProductByGroup and it gives this error  The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ShowProductByGroup(Int32)' in 'BehinFaraz.Controllers.ProductController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter

Comment: public ActionResult ShowGroup()
        {
            return PartialView(database.ProductBrand.ToList());
        }
     

        public ActionResult ShowProductByGroup(int id)
        {
            return View(database.Products.Where(p => p.ProductGroupID == id));
        }

Comment: my friend,ADyson,it doesnt have any problem.it just needed to clean solution in visual studio thanks aloooooooooooooooootttttttttttt

Answer (score 0):

```html
    @using BehinFaraz.Models
@model  Tuple<IEnumerable<ProductBrand>, IEnumerable<ProductGroup>>
<li class="dropdown dropdown-mm" dir="rtl">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products  <b class="caret"></b></a>
<!-- Dropdown Menu -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mm dropdown-menu-persist">
    <li class="row"  dir="rtl">
        <ul class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (var item1 in Model.Item1)
            {
                <li class="dropdown-header "><font color='#01747b'><strong> @item1.ProductBrandTitle</strong></font></li>

            
                foreach (var item2 in Model.Item2.Where(model=>model.ProductBrandID==model.ProductBrand.ProductBrandID) )
                {
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink(item2.ProductGroupTitle,"ShowProductByGroup","Product",new {id=item2.ProductGroupID})</li>
                }
               
            }
        </ul>
       
    </li>
                       
</ul>
```

Comment: you don't need it like that. The `IEnumerable<ProductGroup>` is already a property of ProductBrand (look at your ProductBrand class's properties!). So the model can just be an `IEnumerable<ProductBrand>`. The you can loop through the brands, and for each brand, then loop through all the groups within the brand.

Comment: hello ADyson,whould you plz give me an example for your discription

Comment: See my answer on this page, I already wrote 2 days ago... :-)